# Django: adding a random.py file in project dir destroyed the setting's import in WSGI

Tags: python, django

This seems weird but it has happened a number of times now. I have some artitrary .py file which was just added to the "Project/Project" directory (same directory as my settings.py). 2-3 scripts import from this script.

After adding the script and restarting apache, the django website shows the following errors exclusively:

Error from:

```
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % 
     (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
 [Wed Jul 24 08:10:03 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: 
Could not import settings 'Project.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): 
No module named settings
```

Any advice? Thank you.

Here is a directory repr:

```
Project/
    Project/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        wsgi.py
        something.py
    App/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        models.py
        tasks.py
```

I tried to restore the site by removing something.py and its imports, however nothing worked.

UPDATE: in the wsgi.py file I put

```
print os.getcwd() 
# prior to
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And the result was off! We were in the wrong directory.
It pointed to /home/user/path/to/django/project instead of /home/user, but however it still
does not work!! Which makes no sense because settings.py is right there, it can blatantly import it..

How come this random scenario caused this?? And previous times it did not.
Can someone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: What are the imports at the top of the script ?

Comment: I assume the problematic module isn't actually called something?  What's the real name?  Did you accidentally overload some module from the standard library that Django depends on?

Comment: Here is the main relevant import at (WSGI.py) os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)

Comment: The module is "Summarize.py". It's inside scripts also dont have any names that overload anything

Comment: No __init__.py in your directories ?

Comment: They are present, sorry forgot about them.

Comment: I made an update guys, check itout

Answer (score 1):

WOW, unbelievable. I accidentally had an extra unneeded **init**.py inside the main higher level Project folder... This was causing Project.settings to look at the directory one level too high!!